# Counting the number of true predicates and limiting

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

Is there a specific way I can limit the number of true predicates available using a specified fact?

At the moment I have `total(2).` as a fact.
I thought this would work:

```
:- total(N), #count{x:something_to_limit(x)} = K, K=N.
```

However this doesn't limit the number of something_to_limit predicates to the specified `total(2)` fact where `N` would equal `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` in `x:something_to_limit(x)` is a constant symbol, you probably want to use variables `X`. The constraint

```
:- total(N), #count{X:something_to_limit(X)} = K, K=N.
```

should work.

Comment: This will eliminate all answer sets where the predicate something_to_limit is true for exactly 2 constants (with total(2)). If you want to have the solutions where exactly 2 atoms are true, you need to add `not` before `#count`.